# How to validate a multi tab where each tabs has it’s own validation process

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuex

At the code I’m working on we have a parent.vue
and some components it uses.

```
<Template>
//tab1
            <firstForm :data="data" @on-submit="submit" />
//tab2
            <secondForm :data="data" @on-submit="submit" />
//tab3
            <thirdForm :data="data" @on-submit="submit" />
<\Template>
```

All forms has its own `v-form` with validation, Shall I use `@submit.prevent="validate()"` ?

How can I make it in a way that the `submit.prevent` validate checks if the other tab are validate too. (from the child ones ?, a child checks other child)

Other idea I had is using event bus, but it felt that it is too much.

I have the data from all the tabs in vuex.

Comment: I might not truly understand your question. But If you wanna validate all tab data on `submit` event just have separate validate function for each

Comment: @nosnart but how should I in a parent component when one submits allow that if the others weren't valid ?

Comment: If 1 invalid return to escape the submit